# Laravel issue whilst iterating using Map - (Update Global Variable outside map function)

Tags: loops, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a controller that should return a list of categories. Each should also have a collection of sub-categories. Each sub-category should also have modules. The modules are of two types: the latest modules and most watched modules.

A SUMMARY STRUCTURE I WANT:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: category 1,
        sub_categories: 
            [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: subcategory 1:
                    modules:
                    [
                        latestModules: [...],
                        mostViewedModules[...]

                    ]
                }
            ],
        another sub-category object,
        and another sub-category object
    },
    another category object,
    and another category object,
]
```

My Controller

```
class SeriesController extends Controller
{
    public function getSeries()
    {

        $categories = Category::with('SubCategories')->get();

        $countCats = 0;
        $countSubCats = 0;

        collect($categories)->map(function ($category) use ($countCats, $countSubCats, $categories){

            collect($category->subCategories)->map(function ($subCategory) use ($countSubCats, $categories) {

                collect($categories[$countCats]->subCategories[$countSubCats])
                                    ->put('modules',
                                        SubCategory::with('latestModules', 'mostViewedModules')
                                                    ->where('id', $subCategory->id)->get()
                                    );
                $countSubCats++;
            });

            $countCats++;

        });

        return $categories;

    }
}
```

My Category model

```
class Category extends Model
{

    public function subCategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\SubCategory')
                    ->orderby('name');
    }

}
```

My Subcategory Model

```
    class SubCategory extends Model
{

    public function parentCategory(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
    }

    public function modules()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Module', 'module_category', 'sub_category_id', 'module_id');
    }

    public function latestModules()
    {
        return $this->modules()
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }

    public function mostViewedModules()
    {
        return $this->modules()
                    ->orderBy('views', 'desc');
    }

}
```

My Module Model

```
class Module extends Model
{

    public function subCategories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\SubCategory', 'module_category', 'module_id', 'sub_category_id');
    }
}
```

WHAT I WAS TRYING TO DO

```
1) Get all the categories via Eloquent Query

2) Collect the many categories and Map over them

3) For each ONE category i map over again to single it out into sub-categories

4) For each sub-category i run Eloquent query to return the related modules.
5) Then i put that result into categories original array by using PUT. I wanted to expand on the original $categories array by including the modules.
```

**PROBLEM**

I realize that the loop works and everything is fine, except that the global $categories variable does not update. Its like inside the loops its updated but once we exist the Map loops the value defaults to

```
Category::with('SubCategories')->get()
```